# How to store void pointers of variable size in one single pointer array?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, visual-c++

I have a code which looks something like this

```
  void * mypointer;
  void * array = malloc(sizeof(void*)*10)
  loop{
       mypointer = malloc(some random size);
       memset(mypointer,start,end)
       array[i++] = mypointer++
   }
```

Now this is throwing an exception that

```
  'void*' is unknown size for array and 'void' illeagal with all types
```

**EDIT**

I tried having `**` array also but it also throws an exception.

Comment: `void *` doesn't vary in size... but `void * array` would point at `void`, which has no size, not at `void *`.

Comment: Then how to solve this problem ? I'm kind of stuck and need to have array of these random size void pointers' start address as I'm using it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `array` is supposed to be an array of pointers, use:

```
void ** array = malloc(sizeof(void*)*10)
```

When you use

```
void* array = ...
```

you cannot index `array` like you are doing in the following line.

```
array[i++] = mypointer++;
```

Remember that

```
array[k] = *(array+k);
```

`array+k` can be evaluated only if `sizeof(*array)` can be determined. `sizeof(*array)` cannot determined if `array` is of type `void*`.

Comment: What I did is 
        void ** array = (void **)malloc(sizeof(void*)*10) 
Still it gives error in 
        array[i++] = mypointer++ that void* is of unknown size

Comment: @niyant `sizeof(void)` doesn't make sense.  `sizeof(void*)` if you want the size of a pointer to `void`

Comment: Then How do you index **myarray in this case ??